# Unable to open SSMS from run window

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, ssms

I'm having an issues that bugs me and can't seem to be able to solve it. I have SQL Server 2005 and 2012.
For the 2005 instance this is my path (for both 2005 and 2012 the path that leads straight to the .exe files - as found under the Target on the shortcut properties):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe"

And for the 2012 instance :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"

If I type either `ssms`\ `sqlwb` or `ssms.exe`\ `sqlwb.exe` in the Run window, Windows tells me that it cannot find ssms or sqlwb.

As a side note, I can start other things from the run window (like Visual Studio, or Paint :P and I'm using Windows 7), but the damned instances of SQL Server Management Studio just don't want to start. Anybody got any ideas as to why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Why do you have `.exe` in your path? The path should contain directories not program names.

Comment: That's the target path that's in the shortcut properties. I presume that one needs to have the .exe for the shortcut. I'll update the question to specify that's the path leading straight to the exe files.